# Azure web job read file from directory

Tags: azure, file-io, azure-webjobs

I have a web job published to an empty azure website. In the root directory (D:\home) I have added a new folder called 'company'. When I run my web job I get the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\company\B20150324.txt'.
```

The file is definitely there. I have confirmed with ftp and the sites Kudu CMD directory explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, file was named using a Local DateTime but Azure server is not.